# Back to Top and next and previous buttons Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small piece of JS relating to a back to top button that i know can be shortened but its just a little bit beyond my capabilities. For some one who is good at JS this is a two minute job.
Its a cool bit of code which results in having a back to top and bottom button and a next and previous button too.

The js I need shortened is:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var offset = 300;
        var duration = 500;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
                jQuery('.sidebtn-top').fadeIn(duration);
            } else {
                jQuery('.sidebtn-top').fadeOut(duration);
            }
        });

    jQuery('.sidebtn-top').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
            return false;
        })
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var offset = 300;
        var duration = 500;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
                jQuery('.sidebtn-bttm').fadeIn(duration);
            } else {
                jQuery('.sidebtn-bttm').fadeOut(duration);
            }
     });

    jQuery('.sidebtn-bttm').click(function(){
           jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
          return false;
       });
    });



    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var offset = 300;
        var duration = 500;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
                jQuery('.sidebtn-rt').fadeIn(duration);
            } else {
                jQuery('.sidebtn-rt').fadeOut(duration);
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var offset = 300;
        var duration = 500;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
                jQuery('.sidebtn-lft').fadeIn(duration);
            } else {
                jQuery('.sidebtn-lft').fadeOut(duration);
            }
        });
    });
```

## The html

```
    <a class="sidebtn-rt" href="http://-url-"><div class="arrow-right"></div></a>

    <a class="sidebtn-lft" href=" http://-url-"><div class="arrow-left"></div></a>

    <a class="sidebtn-top" href="#"><div class="arrow-up"></div></a>

    <a class="sidebtn-bttm" href="#"><div class="arrow-down"></div></a>
```

Comment: You only need to use one `jQuery(document).ready` that wraps around all your code. You also only need to declare the `offset` and `duration` variables once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the compressed code that you can try:

- You can remove multiple `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`
- You can club the elements by comma, rather than writing every time (`jQuery('.sidebtn-top, .sidebtn-btt, .sidebtn-rt, .sidebtn-lft')`)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var offset = 300;
  var duration = 500;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
      jQuery('.sidebtn-top, .sidebtn-btt, .sidebtn-rt, .sidebtn-lft').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
      jQuery('.sidebtn-top, .sidebtn-btt, .sidebtn-rt, .sidebtn-lft').fadeOut(duration);
    }
  });

  jQuery('.sidebtn-top, .sidebtn-btt').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var scrollLoc = 0;
    if ($(this).hasClass('sidebtn-btt'))
      var scrollLoc = $(document).height();

    jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: scrollLoc
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sidebtn-rt" href="http://-url-">
  <div class="arrow-right">right</div>
</a>

<a class="sidebtn-lft" href=" http://-url-">
  <div class="arrow-left">left</div>
</a>

<a class="sidebtn-top" href="#">
  <div class="arrow-up">top</div>
</a>

<a class="sidebtn-bttm" href="#">
  <div class="arrow-down">down</div>
</a>
```